# ElasticSearch Not returning all results

Tags: rest, search, elasticsearch

I have this set of Data

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 16,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "tenant1",
      "_type" : "consultation",
      "_id" : "100038",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"id":"100038","patientPin":"2012010000000020","prescriptions":[],"diagnosis":["Amoebiasis"],"patientFirstName":"Scooby","patientLastName":"Doo","documentDate":"06/13/2014"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "tenant1",
      "_type" : "consultation",
      "_id" : "100007",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"id":"100007","patientPin":"2012010000000016","prescriptions":["METHISOPRINOL ISOPRINOSINE"],"diagnosis":["Alcohol Intoxication"],"patientFirstName":"Johnny","patientLastName":"Bravo","documentDate":"06/10/2014"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "tenant1",
      "_type" : "consultation",
      "_id" : "100015",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"id":"100015","patientPin":"2012010000000010","prescriptions":[],"diagnosis":["Amoebiasis"],"patientFirstName":"Tweety","patientLastName":"Bird","documentDate":"06/10/2014"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "tenant1",
      "_type" : "consultation",
      "_id" : "100027",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"id":"100027","patientPin":"2012010000000014","prescriptions":[],"diagnosis":["Food Poisoning"],"patientFirstName":"Marvin","patientLastName":"Martian","documentDate":"06/11/2014"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "tenant1",
      "_type" : "consultation",
      "_id" : "100046",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"id":"100046","patientPin":"2012010000000027","prescriptions":[],"diagnosis":["Amoebiasis"],"patientFirstName":"Yabba","patientLastName":"Doo","documentDate":"06/13/2014"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "tenant1",
      "_type" : "consultation",
      "_id" : "100058",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"id":"100058","patientPin":"2012010000000003","prescriptions":[],"diagnosis":["Amoebiasis"],"patientFirstName":"Elmer","patientLastName":"Fudd","documentDate":"06/13/2014"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "tenant1",
      "_type" : "consultation",
      "_id" : "100042",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"id":"100042","patientPin":"2012010000000021","prescriptions":[],"diagnosis":["Amoebiasis"],"patientFirstName":"Scrappy","patientLastName":"Doo","documentDate":"06/13/2014"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "tenant1",
      "_type" : "consultation",
      "_id" : "100054",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"id":"100054","patientPin":"2012010000000026","prescriptions":[],"diagnosis":["Amoebiasis"],"patientFirstName":"Scooby","patientLastName":"Dum","documentDate":"06/13/2014"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "tenant1",
      "_type" : "consultation",
      "_id" : "100066",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"id":"100066","patientPin":"2012010000000015","prescriptions":[],"diagnosis":["Amoebiasis"],"patientFirstName":"Hippety","patientLastName":"Hopper","documentDate":"06/13/2014"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "tenant1",
      "_type" : "consultation",
      "_id" : "100050",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"id":"100050","patientPin":"2012010000000002","prescriptions":[],"diagnosis":["Amoebiasis"],"patientFirstName":"Daffy","patientLastName":"Duck","documentDate":"06/13/2014"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

However, when I am querying through Google Chromes' Rest Console with this query

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "patientFirstName" : "Scooby"
        }
    }
}
```

It returns all the result here's the URL I am using to search

```
http://localhost:9200/tenant1/consultation/_search
```

I also even did

```
http://localhost:9200/tenant1/consultation/_search?patientLastName:Doo
```

and it still return all results. It supposed to return only one result

Comment: It appears there are two "Scooby"'s, the query should therefore return two results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to this.(add _search?q=)

```
http://localhost:9200/tenant1/consultation/_search?q=patientLastName:Doo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a bool query, this will ensure that it has the following to return it as a result -

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "term": {
                    "patientFirstName": "Scooby"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More information [here.](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)